# Patch a string together to working with a Operator '=='

Tags: c#

I have 8 buttons that all pretty much do the same thing change the `0` to a `1` of the button that i'm pressing `Dout0_Click` & `DoutState0` I'd like to do this without copy and pasting the same bit of code 8 times...

```
    int DoutState0 = 0; // 0(off) or 1(on)

    private void Dout0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DoutState0 == 0)
        {
            DoutState0 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            DoutState0 = 0;
        }
    }
```

So i thought of this bit of code

```
    int DoutNumber = 0; // 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 

    int DoutState0 = 0; // 0(off) or 1(on)
    int DoutState1 = 0;
    int DoutState2 = 0;
    int DoutState3 = 0;
    int DoutState4 = 0;
    int DoutState5 = 0;
    int DoutState6 = 0;
    int DoutState7 = 0;

    public void TogleDOUT()
    {
        string CheckDout = $"DoutState{DoutNumber}";
        Console.WriteLine(CheckDout);  // prints 'DoutState0' and not '0' as expected 

        if (CheckDout == 0)
        {
            //update CheckDout from '0' to '1'
        }
        else
        {
            //update CheckDout from '1' to '0'
        }

    }


    private void Dout0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoutNumber = 0;
        TogleDOUT();
    }
```

But getting this error `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'`

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here...

Comment: The message tells you what you're doing wrong. You're trying to compare a string to an int. CheckDout is a string, 0 is an int.

Comment: What do you mean, you are not sure? You cannot compare the string `"DoutState0"` with the number `0`.

Comment: On a side note, the simplest approach is to set `Control.Tag` to a different number for each of your buttons, and then check it inside a common handler. The [interpolated string operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) which you're using simply creates a string, just as if you called `string.Format("DoutState{0}", DoutNumber)`. It doesn't magically evaluate a private field with the matching name.

Comment: Instead of having 8 variables, why not use an array or a list and access it e.g. by using `doutState[4] = 0`.This way you can easily loop all elements in the array and set them to whatever you like, instead of writing the same assignment 8 times.

Answer (score -3):

Where you have DoutNumber == 0 your 0 needs to be in quotation  marks like `"0"` because it is comparing an int against a string

Comment: It will never equal "0".

Comment: `DoutNumber` is an int: `int DoutNumber`